# Unable to start mongodb servise in ubantu failed to connect on Ubantu 20.04

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ubuntu, nosql, mern

I have tried all previous commands like
`sudo chmod -R 0777 /var/lib/mongodb`

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo mongod --repair
sudo service mongod start
sudo service mongod status
```

first command saying that file not availableand not removed
i also gave the all priveleges to it

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
```

but its not showing any thing
also repairing commands not working
also restart ubantu but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When debugging any problems with a service on Ubuntu try this:

```
# cat /var/log/messages
```

There you may find out more information about the problem.

Also, in your case mongod should be logging to a folder like

```
/var/log/mongod
```

Or something similar, and for that to happen the `mongo` user must have permissions to write there.

Allways look for the log, every service will log something either to their own file or to a system log. And hopefully, inside that log you’ll find the concrete problem that’s preventing your service from starting.